# How can I move the list-view field from the lightning-map to the bottom of the map?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-map

To explain my question: I have the "list-view" as visible, so I can see all the map-markers addresses. Its working correctly for me, but Its populating on the right-hand side of my map.
**I want to move the list to the bottom of the map instead of it being on the right-hand side.**
[image]

**My HTML Code:**

```
<template>
   
   <!-- Mapping. -->
   <lightning-map 

       map-markers={mapMarkers}
       zoom-level={zoomLevel}
       options={mapOptions}
       list-view={listView}
   
   >

   </lightning-map>

</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by the `lightning-map` component, as per [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-map/specification) (there's no property to set the list of items' position).

To achieve what you want, you would have to create your own component that displays a map using a third-party library like Mapbox or [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/).

Comment: Ok, thank you. One more thing can I have a LWC that only displays the list, and one that only displays the map?

Comment: Yes, you can. As long as it is custom, you could do pretty much anything with them.